# Reliably checking if a string is base64 encoded in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, base64

Before I start: Yes, I have checked the other questions and answers on this topic both here and elsewhere.

I have found an example string that the .Net will base64 decode even though it isn't actually base64 encoded. Here is the example:

*Rhinocort Aqueous 64mcg/dose Nasal Spray*

The .Net method Convert.FromBase64String does not throw an exception when decoding this string so my IsBase64Encoded method happily returns true for this string.

Interestingly, if I use the cygwin base64 -d command using this string as input, it fails with the message *invalid input*.

Even more interestingly, the source that I thought that belongs to this executable (http://libb64.sourceforge.net/) "decodes" this same string with the same result as I am getting from the .Net Convert.FromBase64String. I will keep looking hoping to find a clue elsewhere but right now I'm stumped.

Any ideas?

Comment: See [in which cases it throws an exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx). Your string meets the condition (by accident).

Comment: That's the problem, it didn't throw an exception

Comment: The .NET version ignores whitespace characters (specifically, ' ', '\n', '\r', and '\t'), which aren't valid. I believe you get the same result if you use `base64 -di`. There isn't really a way to check that doesn't rely on some kind hueristic. Any string whose length is a multiple of 4, matching [a-zA-Z0-9], is going to be valid to decode but might not represent actual base-64 encoded data.

Comment: Thanks Mike. You're correct about base64 -di "decoding" this string. Looks like I'm going to have to find some other way to encode this data that I can identify as encoded.

Comment: @mikez: You have to add the padding, `=*2` to that regex.

Comment: @Farnarkler: how would you expect to handle data that _is_ actual encoded base64 data, but where the decoded binary data is not valid? I would stick with base64 if it's what's convenient; you still need to do validation post-decode anyway, which will easily catch text that .NET lets pass even when it's obviously not base64-encoded.

Comment: For even more fun, try to make a computer decide if this is Base64, Hexadecimal or a Popband: `"ABBA"`

Answer (score 1):

There's a slightly better solution which also checks the input string length.

I recommend you do a check at the beginning. If the input is null or empty then return `false`.

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/177808/How-to-determine-if-a-string-is-Base-decoded-or

Comment: Unfortunately that is not a solution. The problem is that the string is will base64 decode without failing. However, there is another answer at the bottom of that CodeProject page that uses a regular expression to see if it looks like a base64 encoded text. Not infallible but it might be the best idea I have seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

When strings do pass Base64 decoding and the decoded data has special characters, then perhaps we can conclude that it was not valid Base64 (this depends on the encoding).  Also, sometimes we're expecting the data being passed to be Base64, but sometimes it may not be properly padded with '='.  Therefore, one method uses "strict" rules for Base64 and the other is "forgiving".

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckForBase64()
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(IsBase64DataStrict("eyJhIjoiMSIsImIiOiI2N2NiZjA5MC00ZGRiLTQ3OTktOTlmZi1hMjhhYmUyNzQwYjEiLCJmIjoiMSIsImciOiIxIn0"));
        Assert.IsTrue(IsBase64DataForgiving("eyJhIjoiMSIsImIiOiI2N2NiZjA5MC00ZGRiLTQ3OTktOTlmZi1hMjhhYmUyNzQwYjEiLCJmIjoiMSIsImciOiIxIn0"));
        Assert.IsFalse(IsBase64DataForgiving("testing123"));
        Assert.IsFalse(IsBase64DataStrict("ABBA"));
        Assert.IsFalse(IsBase64DataForgiving("6AC648C9-C08F-4F9D-A0A5-3904CF15ED3E"));
    }
    public bool IsBase64DataStrict(string data)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data)) return false;
        if ((new Regex(@"[^A-Z0-9+\/=]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)).IsMatch(data)) return false;
        if (data.Length % 4 != 0) return false;
        var e = data.IndexOf('=');
        var l = data.Length;
        if (!(e == -1 || e == l - 1 || (e == l - 2 && data[l - 1] == '='))) return false;
        var decoded = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            byte[] decodedData = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
            decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedData);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        //check for special chars that you know should not be there
        char current;
        for (int i = 0; i < decoded.Length; i++)
        {
            current = decoded[i];
            if (current == 65533) return false;
            if (!((current == 0x9 || current == 0xA || current == 0xD) ||
                ((current >= 0x20) && (current <= 0xD7FF)) ||
                ((current >= 0xE000) && (current <= 0xFFFD)) ||
                ((current >= 0x10000) && (current <= 0x10FFFF))))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool IsBase64DataForgiving(string data)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data)) return false;

        //it could be made more forgiving by replacing any spaces with '+' here

        if ((new Regex(@"[^A-Z0-9+\/=]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)).IsMatch(data)) return false;
        
        //this is the forgiving part
        if (data.Length % 4 > 0)
            data = data.PadRight(data.Length + 4 - data.Length % 4, '=');
        
        var e = data.IndexOf('=');
        var l = data.Length;
        if (!(e == -1 || e == l - 1 || (e == l - 2 && data[l - 1] == '='))) return false;
        var decoded = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            byte[] decodedData = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
            decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedData);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        //check for special chars that you know should not be there
        char current;
        for (int i = 0; i < decoded.Length; i++)
        {
            current = decoded[i];
            if (current == 65533) return false;
            if (!((current == 0x9 || current == 0xA || current == 0xD) ||
                ((current >= 0x20) && (current <= 0xD7FF)) ||
                ((current >= 0xE000) && (current <= 0xFFFD)) ||
                ((current >= 0x10000) && (current <= 0x10FFFF))))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```